# How to solve the Dalvik error in adding libs to another project to make a Lite version of my Android app?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

In my app, I have to have two version: Full and Lite.

I am following these tutorials:

- http://bitowl.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/tutorial-how-to-make-full-and-lite-versions/
- http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/

So, I build my full version, and make it a library. This full version uses some other libs, needed to some components.

Then, I create a new project and added the lib created. The problem is when I try to run my lite version, eclipse gives this error:

```
[2012-12-13 13:58:13 - <app> Lite] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lnet/simonvt/timepicker/R$attr;

Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

The simonvt/timepicker is one of the libs that I use in my full version.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Right-click on your project and choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path,
2. then go to order and export section
3. If simonvt/timepicker has a checkmark against it, then deselect it.

I believe that the problem is that the library project is already added and you might be trying to add it again.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the problem something like your way.